# Retrieve a value external to vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a method outside of vue.js that collects a value. I want to get that name inside of the vue model, but not sure how it works.

```js
function retrieval(){
           const retName ="the cook is here"


        }

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   retName:"",

  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <button onclick="retrieval()">Click</button>
{{retName}}

</div>
```

Comment: is your function `retrieval` running before your Vue app has been created or afterwards?

Comment: it will run if a button clicks it

Comment: @Vzupo You can't define a const inside a function and use it like this.
The variables define inside a function is restricted in this scope. You need to define a global variable if you want to use it.

So your function need to "update" a global variable initalize before.